# Ironpython: Function works in CPython, mysterious null pointer exception in IronPython

Tags: python, ironpython, nullreferenceexception, cpython

I'm trying to do something that seems very simple, and falls within the range of standard python. The following function takes a collection of sets, and returns all of the items that are contained in two or more sets.

To do this, while the collection of sets is not empty, it simply pops one set out of the collection, intersects it with the remaining sets, and updates a set of items that fall in one of these intersections.

```
def cross_intersections(sets):
    in_two = set()
    sets_copy = copy(sets)
    while sets_copy:
        comp = sets_copy.pop()
        for each in sets_copy:
            new = comp & each
            print new,         # Print statements to show that these references exist
            print in_two
            in_two |= new      #This is where the error occurs in IronPython
    return in_two
```

Above is the function I'm using. To test it, in CPython, the following works:

```
>>> a = set([1,2,3,4])
>>> b = set([3,4,5,6])
>>> c = set([2,4,6,8])

>>> cross = cross_intersections([a,b,c])
set([2, 4]) set([])
set([4, 6]) set([2, 4])
set([3, 4]) set([2, 4, 6])
>>> cross
set([2, 3, 4, 6])
```

However, when I try to use IronPython:

```
>>> b = cross_intersections([a,b,c])
set([2, 4]) set([])
set([4, 6]) set([2, 4])
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "c:/path/to/code.py", line 10, in cross_intersections
SystemError: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.
```

In the title I said this was a mysterious null pointer exception. I probably have no idea how .NET handles null pointers (I've never worked with a C-like language, and have only been using IronPython for a month or so), but if my understanding is correct, it occurs when you attempt to access some property of an object that points to `null`.

In this case, the error occurs at line 10 of my function: `in_two |= new`. However, I've put `print` statements right before this line that (at least to me) indicate that neither of these objects point to `null`.

Where am I going wrong?

Comment: It seems to be a bug: http://ironpython.codeplex.com/workitem/30386. Should be alredy fixed in trunk.

Comment: Looks like it. I was wondering if this could be the case, but I never like to blame the environment. Put that as an answer and I'll accept it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[It's a bug](http://ironpython.codeplex.com/workitem/30386). It will be fixed in 2.7.1, but I don't think the fix is in the 2.7.1 Beta 1 release.

Answer (score 1):

This is a [bug](http://ironpython.codeplex.com/workitem/30386) still present in the 2.7.1 Beta 1 release.

It has been fixed in [master](https://github.com/IronLanguages/main), and the fix will be included in the next release.

```
IronPython 3.0 (3.0.0.0) on .NET 4.0.30319.235
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import copy
>>>
>>> def cross_intersections(sets):
...     in_two = set()
...     sets_copy = copy.copy(sets)
...     while sets_copy:
...         comp = sets_copy.pop()
...         for each in sets_copy:
...             new = comp & each
...             print new,     # Print statements to show that these references exist
...             print in_two
...             in_two |= new  # This is where the error occurs in IronPython
...     return in_two
...
>>>
>>> a = set([1,2,3,4])
>>> b = set([3,4,5,6])
>>> c = set([2,4,6,8])
>>>
>>> cross = cross_intersections([a,b,c])
set([2, 4]) set([])
set([4, 6]) set([2, 4])
set([3, 4]) set([2, 4, 6])
```