# Ironpython: Debugging a null reference exception

Tags: .net, ironpython, nullreferenceexception

I have previously asked [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6712051/ironpython-function-works-in-cpython-mysterious-null-pointer-exception-in-ironp) question when I was seeing a null pointer exception. In that case it turned out that what I was seeing was in fact a bug in IronPython.

Now I recently came across this error again when using a third party library (written in C#). The library is the [DotSpatial](http://dotspatial.codeplex.com/) library and it turns out that I accidentally created a condition in my IronPython code that led to a side effect in the DotSpatial method breaking. For reference the call and error message are:

```
>>> myScheme.CreateCategories(myLayer.DataSet.DataTable) 
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
SystemError: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.
```

This was particularly difficult to debug because the problem was not with the myScheme object or the DataTable I was passing to its method, but with another property of myScheme that I had set incorrectly, which I didn't even know that CreateCategories accessed.

To figure out what was going wrong here I had to read through the DotSpatial [source code](http://dotspatial.codeplex.com/SourceControl/changeset/view/3f292a701a9d#DotSpatial.Symbology/DotSpatial.Symbology/FeatureScheme.cs). While I don't have too much trouble doing that, I was wondering if there are any easier ways to debug such an error? Or am I stuck with bad error messages because I'm working with IronPython and a third party library?

Answer (score 3):

There are two command-line switches to get IronPython to show more exception information: `-X:ExceptionDetail` and `-X:ShowClrExceptions`. One or both of those should give you the full stack trace to where the `NullReferenceException` occurred.

Comment: Awesome. I just spent an hour trying to figure out how to do this. Thanks.